# Grid DetailRow only if property exists

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

When I use the following code to enable the detail template, it works but I would like to only show a detail template if a specific property (Category) exists. Currently it renders an expand icon if there is no detail template content. The problem is that I cannot use an `*ngIf` directive on the template element itself as I don't have access to the property.

```
<template kendoDetailTemplate let-dataItem>
          <section *ngIf="dataItem.Category">
            <header>{{dataItem.Category?.CategoryName}}</header>
            <article>{{dataItem.Category?.Description}}</article>
          </section>
</template>
```

[image]

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKERCaoU4PEAi7Qya9VT?p=preview)

[Github feature request](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/106)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently such functionality is not supported. You can log this as a feature request in the kendo-angular2 [repo](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2)